# Why did a TFS merge auto-merge a file, instead of prompting me to manually merge the file?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

We are currently using TFS 2015 for source control and project management. We're also using Visual Studio 2019. The team I'm on has a main branch in TFS, with branches off main for development isolation. Today I merged the main branch into my dev branch. During the process TFS/VS 2019 informed me that there was a conflict in one file, Proficiency.cs. However, TFS auto-merged the file. After I checked in the changes, I looked at Proficiency.cs. It was wrong, the version in my dev branch didn't have the changes that it should have from the main branch.

Why didn't TFS give me a chance to review the conflict? Is it because we're using TFS 2015? Or is there some step or configuration in VS 2019 I should set to allow me to review the conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the system automatically attempts to **AutoResolve All** conflicts. To change the option, from the menu bar choose **Tools**, **Options**, and then in the **Options** dialog box, navigate to **Source Control**, **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**. Clear the **Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated** checkbox.

[image]

More details, check documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts?view=azure-devops